# Fraction Simplification

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am working on some calc2 power series problem and Im not sure why I can not simplify the following: $(\frac{(-2)^{n+1}(x-4)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!})(\frac{(n!)}{(-2)^n(x-4)^n})$. If someone could kindly help me simplify this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Products of factorials and powers are your friends in expressions like this, because they all are multiplicative factors which you can divide out at will. Remember, all the factors in the numerators get lumped together, and ditto with the denominators, so the fact that it is written as two fractions multiplied together should pose no obstacle. This is the sort of arrangement you should be happy to see.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{(-2)^{n+1}(x-4)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\dfrac{n!}{((-2)^n)(x-4)^n}\\
= \dfrac{-2(-2)^{n}(x-4)^{n}(x+4)}{(n+1)n!}\dfrac{n!}{((-2)^n)(x-4)^n}\\
=\dfrac{-2(x+4)}{(n+1)}$$